# ASP.NET MVC How can i prevent jquery from loading twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, fullcalendar

I am implementing a fullcalendar (see [fullcalendar.io](http://fullcalendar.io)) in a .cshtml View in a ASP.NET MVC application. I've inserted all the javascript code in the `index.cshtml` file but it did not show the calendar in the browser. 
The files needed for the fullcalendar are also imported in the `index.cshtml` file.

**Code**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/calendar-js/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/calendar-js/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/calendar-js/moment.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/calendar-js/fullcalendar.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/calendar-js/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/calendar-css/fullcalendar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/calendar-css/fullcalendar.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/calendar-css/fullcalendar.print.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/calendar-css/fullcalendar.print.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I got the

> "TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function"

error in the browser console.

I found out that it is a problem with jQuery and I've seen in the Network-tab of my browser that jQuery seems to load twice. First the jQuery file I referenced  in my **.cshtml** file and another jQuery file which seems to be needed in a `_LayOut.cshtml` file:

```
<environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-K+ctZQ+LL8q6tP7I94W+qzQsfRV2a+AfHIi9k8z8l9ggpc8X+Ytst4yBo/hH+8Fk">
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
        </script>
        <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
```

I have tried:

- to run the `index.cshtml` without the jQuery reference of that file. It just made it worse because I got "jQuery not found"-like errors in the browser console.
- To run the `index.cshtml` file with all the jQuery references but I deleted the jQuery reference in the `_LayOut.cshtml` file. The fullcalendar kind of showed up but in a strange way. So my conclusion is that those 2 jQuery references are conflicting with each other. Although the fullcalendar showed up, i don't think it is the right thing to do it that way.
- CDN references instead of local files. It did not work out.

How to solve this problem of the conflicting jQuery imports?

Comment: Try to use the same file. Change the reference to the same file-path.

Comment: @Nikolaus Thansk for your answer. I have already tried that but it could not find the file. I have found a temporarily workaround(excluding the jQuery files in the _LayOut file) but i do not think it is a real solution either.

Comment: If you don’t use it in your _Layout.cshtml, it shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: you have included fullCalendar's JS, CSS and print-CSS twice in each case. Do you understand the difference between the .js and .min.js files? One is just a compressed version of the other. .js (and .css) should be used in debug scenarios, .min.js (and .min.css) are for "live" use - when a small file size is more important than being able to understand the code.

Comment: And yeah don't include jQuery twice either. The way to "prevent jQuery from loading twice" is...don't include it twice in your page. It's unclear why it wasn't valid when you ran it with jQuery included only via the Layout page, but perhaps you had the wrong version of jQuery or something, or perhaps it's loaded too late, after the fullCalendar code runs, it's not so clear from your code whether that's the case. Either way you should ensure it, and any other script or CSS file, is never included twice, otherwise you'll get unpredictable results.

Comment: P.S. you also haven't set the correct media query on the fullcalendar "print" CSS, which is probably why it shows up in a "strange way" - i.e. the print-mode styles are overriding the screen-mode styles. You need the `media='print'` attribute on your print CSS entry